# How to make modal behind the bottom tab bar in React Native

Tags: react-native

I created a bottom tab bar, when press on the bottom tab bar, will toggle a modal. Now my modal is blocking the bottom tab bar, so I am not able to press on the bottom tab bar to close my modal.

Any solution for this? I've tried zIndex, and adjust the marginBottom for the modal (move it up), but both are not working

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, you can not do this. As told in [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/) piece of documentation:

> A modal displays content that temporarily blocks interactions with the main view.

So this is indeed the expected behavior.

Comment: it will block the whole screen included my bottom tab bar?

Comment: Yep, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with

```
fullScreen={false}
transparent={true}
```

then set margin-bottom